# Extract city names from large text with php

Tags: php

Hello i have an question here. Suppose that i have a long string which includes country names between other words.

```
$str = "Department of Cardiology, West China Hospital, Sichuan University, No. 37 GuoXue Street, Boston,United states of america."
```

My goal is to extract all the country name of it. And I achieved it by following steps.

```
$str= str_replace(',', ' ', $str);
$var_array = preg_split('/(\|,|\.|-|\(|\)| )/', $str);
foreach($var_array as$data)
{
    echo $data;
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

**Result**

```
Department
of
Cardiology

West
China
Hospital
Sichuan
University

No

37
GuoXue
Street

Boston
United
states
of
america
```

But as you can see I cannot deal with country with multiple word names for eg "United states of america" as they are separated. Of course fix this issue manually is not an option as my real dataset is quite large.

Comment: Just split on the comma character maybe?

Comment: This is impossible to achieve since any word could theoretically be the name of a country/city. You need to cross reference the string with an existing database of all countries/cities you want to match.

Comment: Is there any particular pattern to the string that would allow you to unambiguously identify parts of it as the country? E.g. everything after the last `,` is the country? If not… that's a pretty tough problem.

Comment: @Ruben Thanks for your kind reply but the main problem is that in some cases there are white  spaces instead of commas.

Comment: @thepieterdc how can i match the whole string with database table.Can you please explain.

Comment: @deceze there is no such static pattern. Please help me out from this situation.

Comment: If there's no pattern at all… then you're quite far up the creek. As pointed out above, get a database of all possible names and go through them to find them in each string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and traverse the string from opposite direction i.e in reverse order separating by comma. Because if you are using google location api then at last there will be always country name.

So you can do something like this :-

$address = array_reverse($str);
$address = explode(',', $address);

Comment: i have already tried this.But there is no such static pattern that country name will always appear after last comma.

Comment: @YugamUppal sorry brother then it is difficult to fetch the exact country name as it 's position is not fixed.